# Setting universal Environment variables for Maven in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I have a large number of Maven projects that all depend on certain environment variables.  They are the same ones for all projects.  I am aware that I can create a run configuration for a given project, but I want to basically have the run configuration work for all my projects without having to set it up specifically.

I am open to having Eclipse either read from my .bash_profile, or loading them in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's OK to have multiple maven launch configurations, just setup the first configuration and create the others as copies, so you don't have to enter common information over and over.

If you need the flexibility to later change those environment variables (without having to edit many locations), try the following:

First go to `Preferences > Run/Debug > String Substitution` and create one or more new "variables" (name x value x description), e.g., name = myVar, value = 13

Then in a m2e launch configuration (`Run As ... > Maven Build ...`) in the `Environment` tab define environment variables using the variables from step 1 as their values, e.g., name = myEnvVar, value = ${myVar}. This should pass an environment variable myEnvVar=13 into your maven build.

Instead of typing ${myVar} you can also click on `Variables...` while editing the environment variable and select your variable from the list.

Now changing the variable from step 1 (myVar) will affect all your launch configurations which refer to it.